How to use `git config --get-colorbool`?
I tried to use git config --get-colorbool to make my custom script emulate how normal Git commands decide when to color output.
However, unlike normal comands and contrary to what manual says, the command ignores whether stdout is TTY or not.
Additionally, it prints bools I pass to it, for some reason.
Here's what I did:
git config --local color.ui always
git config --get-colorbool color.ui ; echo $?

git config --local color.ui never
git config --get-colorbool color.ui ; echo $?

git config --local color.ui auto
git config --get-colorbool color.ui ; echo $?
git config --get-colorbool color.ui 2>&1 | cat ; echo $?
git config --get-colorbool color.ui true ; echo $?
git config --get-colorbool color.ui false ; echo $?

The output is:
+ git config --local color.ui always
+ git config --get-colorbool color.ui
+ echo 0
0
+ git config --local color.ui never
+ git config --get-colorbool color.ui
+ echo 1
1
+ git config --local color.ui auto
+ git config --get-colorbool color.ui
+ echo 0
0
+ git config --get-colorbool color.ui
+ cat
+ echo 0
0
+ git config --get-colorbool color.ui true
true
+ echo 0
0
+ git config --get-colorbool color.ui false
false
+ echo 0
0

(My Git version is 2.34.1)
What am I doing wrong?

I can't repro your results with true and false. You seem to be misreading the documentation regarding the TTY check; the command makes no check at runtime, but you can pass in a second argument to check what the behavior would be with or without a TTY.

@tripleee The manual says "If stdout-is-tty is missing, then checks the standard output of the command itself..."
Edit: To clarify, my interpretation is that it checks the output to determine if it's a TTY or not.
